# ibm-cloud: db2 Provision in progress

Tags: ibm-cloud

I tried to create a new service and for some reason the status is stuck at "provision in progress"
I cannot delete the service and create a new one. My progress on my project is stuck because I can only have one lite DB service.

[image]

I am not sure what I should do next

Help is really appreciated

Comment: Wait for it to be done. The Db2 on Cloud Lite service is currently migrated, see the FAQ in the docs. It is a non-production service without any guarantees. Or provision a paid service instance.

Comment: @data_henrik. Do you know any approximation on how long this might take? I am a student following a ibm course and using the free services.

Comment: You might want to go to the IBM Cloud support page and try the chat. I don't have any insights

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, but it was resolved after going back to Dashboard and selecting db2 service again (while the status was still "provision in progress").